# 12.10 has Python 3.2.3 default, does this impact existing python tools?

Tags: python3

Ubuntu 12.10 has Python 3.2.3 default, so does this impact existing python tools, designed to be used with older python 2.x? There was a discussion in [HackerNews](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4668080) on the same. I'm a bit apprehensive now to guide someone in python world moving to latest 12.10 for the reason it comes with Python3.2

I'm currently installing 12.10 from 12.04. Can I work side by side on Python versions 2.x and 3.x without breaking the system? Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

No, this does *not* impact existing Python2 tools.

12.10 has Python3 installed by default, but that doesn't mean it's the "default Python". Python2 is at this point also installed by default (AFAIK), and importantly, /usr/bin/python is still a symlink to python2.7.

The transition to Python3 has been done such that it has zero effect on existing Python2 applications. 2 and 3 are parallel installable, and install their site packages in different locations.

If you want your app to use Python3, you'll have explicitly change the shebang to:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

See [Python 3 on Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python/3) for more details.

Comment: The default python on my 12.10 install is Python 2.7.3.

Comment: thanks that helps. And sorry I could not vote up your answer, Low on reputation now. :)

Comment: More importantly, there is currently no plan to ever make /usr/bin/python point to python3. Even when python 2.x is not installed by default, apps can still explicitly depend on it, and /usr/bin/python will still work for them.

Comment: FYI, there is now a plan to make python3 the default/only Python installation for Ubuntu 14.04: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python/3

Answer (score 0):

the hash bang should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env pythonX.Y.Z
```

and **not**

```
#!/usr/bin/pythonX.Y.Z
```

This way the code will work even if python is not in `/usr/bin/python` but say `/usr/local/bin/python` or `/opt/python2.7/bin/python` and all is in `$PATH`.

It even makes the code work on OSX. IIRC it should also load the current runtime on windows[1].

[1] http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/

Comment: This looks like a comment to jderose's answer rather than an answer to the question

Comment: But that should be ok for ubuntu as it puts it on /usr/bin/python

Comment: You should not usr /usr/bin/env python, as it will break things like virtualenv, and hash-bang replacement when installing with different versions of python for apps that support them. You should use #!/usr/bin/python and work toward supporting python3.