# Changing Python default in 12.04 LTS

Tags: application-development, python, default-programs, python-2.7, python3

I have downloaded and installed python 3.2.3 for Ubuntu/Debian. Also IDLE IDE for 3.2.3.

If I execute IDLE for 3.2.3 explicitely, 3.2.3 runs under IDLE and all is well.

But if I go to a terminal session and simple run Python, it defaults to python 2.7.3. Also my Python commercial IDE (Wingware) defaults to Python 2.7.3.

How can I change my global Python default to be 3.2.3 instead of 2.7.3?

Comment: In a terminal, you can just run `python3`. There's probably a setting somewhere for Wing.

Comment: Yes python3 works fine from terminal. But I cannot seem to find the right path to the binary so that I can tell Wing to use it. I installed it with synaptic -any idea where it is? I am new to Linux.

Comment: It should be `/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: Thanks - will check out. As I was reading this morning about Linux file system I figured that's where it would be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Don't do it

Since many important programs are written in python changing default python may crash your system, so set python for individual apps.
You can locate python3 at `/usr/bin/python3`
. <strike>If you want python3 by default try Ubuntu 12.10</strike>

Comment: Understood. python3 works fine from terminal. But I cannot seem to find the right path to the binary so that I can tell Wing to use it. I installed it with synaptic -any idea where it is? I am new to Linux.

Comment: Sure?. I'm using 12.10 and python 2.7 seems to be the default.

Comment: @Mikey: at /usr/bin/python3

Comment: @Javier Rivera: Strange!, Default python in 12.10 is python 3.2, Please recheck it :)

Comment: Rechecked. It's 2.7. I have also find this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/202483/12-10-has-python-3-2-3-default-does-this-impact-existing-python-tools.

Looks like python3 is installed by default in 12.10, but python3 is not the default python for 12.10.

Comment: @Tachyons: There's no plan to make Python 3 run when you type `python` in a terminal. Even when Python 2 is dropped from the default installation (which hasn't happened yet), Python 3 will be `python3`. Debian & Ubuntu are playing it that way to avoid breaking things.

Comment: @Tachyons - /usr/bin/python3 works fine in Wing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend overwriting the system python binaries.

I mainly use Perl and [Perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/) for testing code and new Perl releases.

You may want to check out something like [Pythonbrew](http://www.howopensource.com/2011/05/how-to-install-and-manage-different-versions-of-python-in-linux/) that will allow you to maintain your system Python while providing you a sandbox to play in with your newer distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where someone changed my default python fom 2.x to 3.x and that broke *everything*. So, if anyone has the same problem as me (and yea blah blah do it at your own risk) you need to do the following:

1. Make sure that `/usr/bin/python` is a link: `ls -l /usr/bin/python` should give you at the end `/usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python3`
2. `sudo rm /usr/bin/python` removes the link
3. Finally, create a new link by doing `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python`

### WARNING

Don't do this if everything is working fine! I kept getting syntax errors because python3 has to have print() functions have brackets, and my filesystem was made with python2. This fixed it.