# I accidentally deleted /usr/bin/python. How do I restore it?

Tags: python

Trying to set the default Python version to 2.7, I ran this command:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python*
```

Now when I type `python` or `python2.7`, I see these error messages:

```
bash: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory
bash: /usr/bin/python2.7: No such file or directory
```

What happened? Should I have run the `rm` command? How can I undo it?

Comment: Never remove system files like this. Why did you even consider doing this? Setting the default Python version on your system is not done by removing files, and you should not perform this change. Read this question: [Changing Python default](http://askubuntu.com/questions/215710/changing-python-default-in-12-04-lts) for more details.

Answer (score 7):

Well, isn't normal that if you remove an executable, the system can't find it anymore?

`/usr/bin/python` is a symlink provided by the **python-minimal** package. You can restore it reinstalling the package:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-minimal
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have `python2.7-minimal` (or any of the other variants) installed, you should have the file `/usr/bin/python2.7` present. Normally, `/usr/bin/python` will be symlinked to this file, so that a simple call of `python` actually ends up running /usr/bin/python2.7.

```
me@banshee:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Apr 17  2012 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Apr 17  2012 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2989480 Aug  1 01:40 /usr/bin/python2.7
```

If you **do** have `/usr/bin/python2.7` but you're missing `/usr/bin/python`, you can simply recreate it from the command line:

```
you@yourbox:~$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

If you're missing `/usr/bin/python2.7`, you'll need to reinstall it (again) as proposed by the other answers. Please post back here if that's the case.

Comment: it appears that I also somehow deleted the usr/bin/python* ....since I am not expert in ubuntu and I don't know how the system works, I had to reinstall the whole system again..hope I will learn from my mistakes..thanks

Answer (score 3):

From a terminal, type `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7`