# My Ubuntu terminal commands seem to be running on python

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, security, python-2.7

When I run a wrong command on my Ubuntu terminal, instead of echo-ing "command not found", the terminal does nothing, and when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it is echo-ing some python exception stack trace. Is something wrong? How can I fix this?

For example, when I enter "sdf", it does nothing. "sdf" is not a valid command.

[image: When I enter an invalid command, terminal does nothing.]

But when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it prints this python exception stack trace.

[image: When I press ctr-C it is echo-ing some python exception stack]

The stack trace is different every time.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, so python2 is the default

```
$ type python python2 python3
python is /usr/bin/python
python2 is /usr/bin/python2
python3 is hashed (/usr/bin/python3)
$ readlink /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python3
python2.7
python2.7
python3.4
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
$ python3 --version
Python 2.7.6
$ readlink /usr/bin/python3.4
$
```

- `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python` did not help.
- `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3` threw an error

**Update**:
So after trying a lot of approaches, I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu. Follow [wjandrea's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/979632/442477) and the comments, seem to be on point in identifying the problem.

Comment: Can you share contents of .bashrc and enter gnome-terminal in Xterm (open it by clicking Win Superkey and typing Xterm).

Comment: I can open gnome-terminal from Xterm, but there it also seems to be executing with python. This is my .bashrc: https://pastebin.com/rTad881Q

Comment: What is the output of `python2 -c 'import usercustomize; print usercustomize.__file__'`

Comment: The stack trace is different every time. And it is "ImportError: No module named usercustomize"

Comment: Try reinstalling gnome-terminal itself. In xterm execute this : `sudo apt-get remove gnome-terminal && sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal`

Comment: @Hannibal I can't see how that would help. Have you read my answer?

Comment: @wjandrea You answer approaches the problem accurately. I can see the infinite loop of Py3->Py2->Py3 ..... Reinstalling gnome won't help I agree. I think he can install an additional Python3 the place it's executable under default Python3 that would work right ?

Comment: Sort of related: [I accidentally deleted /usr/bin/python. How do I restore it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/218919/301745)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/etc/bash.bashrc` defines a function `command_not_found_handle`, which calls `/usr/lib/command-not-found`, which is a Python 3 script. This handler is called for commands that Bash can't find.

So as a bandage fix, you can unset the handler:

```
unset -f command_not_found_handle
```

#### Update 2:

After some discussion with OP, it turns out the issue is caused by a Python 2.7 executable accidentally placed at /usr/bin/python3.4. (So my first update was not very useful, but it's in [revision 4](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/979632/4) if you want to read it). If this happens to you, **don't restart your computer!**  Some parts of the GUI depend on Python 3. You will probably need to keep the terminal open too.

BTW, this explains the infinite loop when calling an unknown command at the Bash prompt. `/usr/lib/command-not-found` has this section in it:

```py
if sys.version < '3':
    # We might end up being executed with Python 2 due to an old
    # /etc/bash.bashrc.
    import os
    if "COMMAND_NOT_FOUND_FORCE_PYTHON2" not in os.environ:
        os.execvp("python3", [sys.argv[0]] + sys.argv)
```

Which means when it gets executed by Python 2, it calls `python3`, but since `python3` is actually Python 2, the process repeats.

#### Update 3:

OP ended up reinstalling Ubuntu, but I was curious so I opened a VM, caused a similar issue (if not the same issue), and fixed it.

1. Caused the problem

   ```
   sudo cp /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python3.4
   ```
2. Confirmed the problem

   - Ran `python3 --version`, got `Python 2.7.6`
   - Tried running `sdf`, had to press Ctrl+C to stop the loop
3. Fixed it:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3.4-minimal
   ```

   The package `python3.4-minimal` provides the Python 3.4 executable itself. All the other packages I checked (`python3`, `python3.4`, `python3-minimal`) depend on `python3.4-minimal` for that reason.

(OP and I stumbled through this solution the first time around. For more details about what I tried, what else I messed up, and how I fixed it, read [revision 9 of this answer](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/979632/9).)

Comment: I think that is what happened. I always use different python packages with virtualenv sandboxing, but recently I might have accidentally installed some version of python globally. The outputs are as follows:

type python 3: python3 is hashed (/usr/bin/python3);
python3 --version: Python 2.7.6

So looks like python3 is actually a link to python 2. Should I use the reinstallation command?

Comment: @IshtiaqueKhan OK, looks like you've accidentally installed `python2.7` at `/usr/bin/python3.4`. You might want to run `python --version` to check that it's unaffected.

Comment: readlink /usr/bin/python3.4 does not print anything. I have compiled all this into the question.

Comment: @IshtiaqueKhan I forgot to mention, don't restart your computer! Some parts of the GUI depend on Python 3. You will probably want to keep the terminal open too.

Comment: @IshtiaqueKhan You could try reinstalling `python3-minimal`, but I expect it will throw an error too.

Comment: If it's *only* the executable that's the problem, you could download the python3-minimal package, extract it somewhere, then copy the executable to /usr/bin/python3. (Sorry, I tried to start a chat, but it's not working properly).

Comment: @IshtiaqueKhan Thanks for the accept, and glad you got it fixed! How did you end up fixing it? That info may help other folks in the future.

Comment: You are right, restarting totally messed things up and I lost my dashboard and a lot of UI. So I tried to install python3 minimal, but ended up with the dependency requirement cycle python3, python3 minimal and some other packages. So the only last attempt left was to re-build python3 from source. I thought I would be much better off by backing up my data and getting rid of Ubuntu 14 altogether and installing Ubuntu 16. Thanks a lot, you were on point though.