# Unable to reinstall python after accidetally deleting the python interpreter

Tags: apt, python

My python 2 and 3 interpreters in /usr/bin somehow got deleted and now I am unable to reinstall either. I see that similar questions have been asked earlier([I accidentally deleted /usr/bin/python. How do I restore it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/218919/972316)) but trying to reinstall using `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7` fails with the following message, and a list of about 15 packages:

```
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` it fails with the following error message:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
/usr/bin/python2.7: can't open file '/usr/lib/python2.7/py_compile.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package python2.7-minimal (--configure):
 installed python2.7-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-minimal:
 python-minimal depends on python2.7-minimal (>= 2.7.15~rc1-1~); however:
  Package python2.7-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 python2.7-minimal
 python-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This happens despite setting `PYTHONHOME` to `/usr/local/lib` or `/usr/lib`, prior to running the above command.

Trying to reinstall python2.7-minimal first also produces the same errors.

I have no trouble accessing the terminal, and attempting to reinstall python3 using `sudo apt-get install python3-all` returns the same error as earlier - `E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution)`, and also lists a few packages.

Comment: Edited the question. Answers in the linked question did not solve the issue.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Which of the answers in the linked question failed you? What were the results/error messages. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I Resolve dpkg dependency?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252777/how-can-i-resolve-dpkg-dependency)

Answer (score 0):

remove the libraries that came along with python using,

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

then update,

```
 sudo apt update
```

then install python by,

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7
```

Comment: It looks like no such operations - install/remove/reinstall, etc are going through. They all come up with the same error of unmet dependencies and ask me to use `apt --fix-broken install`.