# Python 3 with Pylab on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apt, python3

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm learning via Python 2.7.3 (specifically Pylab - IPython, NumPy, SciPy and Matplotlib). I thought it's better to learn the newest version of Python. Using apt-get tells me that all of the above are the most recent versions. The reasons are explained here:
[Changing Python default in 12.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215710/changing-python-default-in-12-04-lts)

So I apt-get python3 and ipython3, but how to have the latest Pylab set for my Python3 interpreter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu/Debian treats `python` and `python3`, and their associated libraries as different packages (rather than one being an upgraded version of the other), since there are fairly few libraries which have a common codebase executable in both python 2 and 3.

Thus, you want `python3-numpy`, `python3-scipy`, `python3-matplotlib`, etc. Unfortunately, `python3-matplotlib` is not available in 12.04 (it is available from 13.04). You might be able to find a PPA containing it, but I personally don't know one to recommend.

(Other libraries you might want to consider for a scientific python setup might include `sympy`, `pandas`, and the various `scikit` packages).

*Edit:* Learning python 3 rather than 2 is a sensible goal, but if you're restricted to 12.04 you're likely to find support lacking in a number of libraries. That being the case, the best course is probably to use python 2 while ensuring you write forward-compatible code - see the [official porting guide](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html) for suggestions.