# which version of python is installed?

Tags: python

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 in my VirtualBox. Is python installed by default? If not, How can I install python?

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/220308/is-python-available-in-any-ubuntu-installation and http://askubuntu.com/questions/202483/12-10-has-python-3-2-3-default-does-this-impact-existing-python-tools

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Running `python --version` in a terminal will show you which version of python is currently installed. Python *does* come by default on ubuntu 12.10 (version 2.7.3) [source](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/python/python)

edit: it has come to my attention that not only is python (2.7.3) available, but also python3 (3.2.3)

Answer (score 0):

To test this type `python` in a terminal to access python 2.7 and `python3` to access python 3. In 12.10 **both** python 2.7 and python 3 are installed **by default**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is installed by default. All Linux distros that I am aware of install python as a lot of default scripts are python.

If you want to see if a piece of software is installed and if there are multiple versions of it, what versions you have installed on your system, this is a good way to find them:

```
aptitude search ^python[0-9] | grep ^i
```

If you ever find yourself wanting to install python:

```
aptitude install python
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Enter this command in a terminal emulator window
`python -V`
which will provide you complete version detail.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that intent to assign the "python" command to python3 eventually ceased;  "python" still means python2 on many systems.
So, issue two commands, `python2 --version` and `python3 --version` (and also `python --version` to be sure).

This won't reveal any private or isolated installations.

> How can I install python?

First, decide which version and features you want (plain python, scientific/math, ipython...)